# Can't Git Clone a Repository on PyCharm

Tags: python, git, pycharm

I am trying to git clone snntorch (a Python-based spiking neural network simulating package) using PyCharm as an IDE.

I have did this a few times before with no problems, however with snntorch I am running into a problem I have never seen before. On PyCharm when I look at the project tree, the snntorch files are not there after git-cloning:

[image]

Here are the steps I have taken as usual:

Opened PyCharm and pressed 'Get from VCS'.

Then I keep the directory the same as all my PyCharm projects: C\Users\xxx\PyCharmProjects and paste the URL from here: https://github.com/jeshraghian/snntorch.

I can see the snntorch files in the file explorer, but not on PyCharm project tree:

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: is the local folder with the files in the pycharm project folder? You might need to add the path to the python libs path

Comment: @Petronella Sorry I am not sure how to check this. I can see all the snntorch files in the PyCharm project folder (I have included this image above if that's what you mean).

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the Git Clone approach in any IntelJ product.

Click the `Git` on the menu bar

[image]

Click `Clone` which will result in the following windows

[image]

Copy the `Git url` which is available from GitHub.You can click the `Green` icon and copy and paste the `url`

`https://github.com/jeshraghian/snntorch.git`

[image]

Paste the `url` to the URL section from on the previous pop-up windows

Then click clone to retrieve the file.

Comment: I tried this but got the same result. Still not working.